# Unable to load dynamic content in multiple $(window).on("load", function(){}) using safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, safari

Hi i am facing a problem here while loading  dynamic content in multiple dropdown  using `$(window).on("load", function(){})`  in chrome it is working fine but in safari i am unable to get the dynamic content in dropdown none of them working 
below is my code

```
$(window).on("load", countryLoad);
function countryLoad() {

var urlink = " http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/Service1.svc/getCou";
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: urlink,
    success: function (resp) {
        var select = document.getElementById("dpdclt");
        var data = "";


        document.getElementById("dpdclt").options.length = 0;
        $("#dpdclt").append($("<option></option>").val(0).html('Select Country'));
        for (var i = 0; i < resp.length; i++) {

            $("#dpdclt").append($("<option></option>").val(resp[i].Sno).html(resp[i].Country));
        }



    },
    error: function (e) {

        window.plugins.toast.showLongBottom("Check your connection settings");

    }
});};
```

like the above function i have 6 other functions which i have to load on page load

2. `$(window).on("load",function2);`
3. `$(window).on("load",function3);`
4. `$(window).on("load", function4)`;
5. `$(window).on("load", function5);`

Here when the page loads in the dropdown im getting only '**Select Country**' in the dropdown it is not loading dynamic contents

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can use `window.onload`, but you may notice that recent browsers don't fire `window.onload` when you use the **back/forward** history buttons.

You can try one of the below code if you want to execute something on page load.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Page loaded
});
```

OR

```
$(function(){
    //Page loaded
});
```

EDIT: Try this

```
window.onload = function(){
   //Page loaded
};
```

Or if you want to use jQuery then try this

```
$(window).bind('load', function(){
   //Page loaded
});
```

Still facing error check your console for any errors...

Comment: The $(document).ready(function(){
    //Page loaded
});  solution worked..

Comment: that's great :)

Comment: `jQuery.bind()` is deprecated... don't use it, use `.on()` instead.  Don't set `window.onload`... it's a bad way to set event handlers as there can only be one.  -1 for also not explaining the differences between `document.ready` and `window.onload`.

Comment: @Brad yes Ur completely right but OP didn't mentioned which jQuery version is using and that's the reason I have added all the possible solutions.. thanx for -1 ;) there are many articles available though to finding out difference so as per my thoughts I don't think I need to write all explanation here OP is enough capable to find out